# How to place an imageview in between space of two textview android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

Hi I am using two textview one after another in left side and at right side is rating bar text and rating bar. I need to place an imageview between two of them.
How to achieve this?

Here is code which I tried.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#00A8E1"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total_expreince"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Total Experience"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total_expreince_years"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/total_expreince"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="7 Years"
        android:textColor="#E1D246" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launchers" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Ratingbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="Rating "
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
        style="@style/customRatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Ratingbar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Ratingbar"
        android:isIndicator="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
  my output is as follow
```

[image]
   Expected output is:
   [image]

Comment: how look your current output?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7g4uV.png @ChiragSavsani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

activity_main.xml

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#80000000"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#00a8e1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_expreince"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Experience"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_expreince_years"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="7 Years"
                    android:textColor="#E1D246" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#00a8e1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Ratingbar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Rating "
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
                     style="@style/Yourratingbarstyle "
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:isIndicator="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"  --> shape xml in drawable
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Imageview shape :  shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dip"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="#00a8e1" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dip"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#EEE" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And your desired output:

[image: And your desired output]

Answer (score 0):

It can be something like below code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#80000000"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_expreince"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:text="Total Experience"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_expreince_years"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/total_expreince"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="7 Years"
                    android:textColor="#E1D246" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Ratingbar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:text="Rating "
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:text="******** "
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTE:** change imageview according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using table layout within the relative or linear layout

```
<LinearLayout>
<TableLayout>
 <TableRow>
       <TextView> </TextView>
       <ImageView> </ImageView>
       <TextView> </TextView>
 </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```